# Should I rollback this approved edit?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

On my run through the edit queue, I noticed [this edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4238589), which I tried to reject only to find it had been approved by the time I clicked the button.

It seems (to me) to be a borderline case of radical change. In a case like this it's unclear whether the OP is actually dealing with the code he pasted into the answer, or just pasted it badly.

Should this be rolled back, or should I assume it's a minor issue and leaving off the bits of HTML tags was a posting mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this were in an answer, editing it would be fine, because I'd say that the the *intent* of the author is clear.

However, this is a question, and questions are different.  Despite the fact that it appears that the author *intended* the tag to be closed, by fixing problems in the question you risk fixing the problem that caused the question to need to be asked.  If there was a comment on the post indicating that the author recognized it was a posting mistake, not an error in the real code, then fixing it for them would be fine, but there is no such comment.

There has been edits since, so a proper "rollback" wouldn't be good, as well as tag changes which look fine.  If you want to revert that code block to its original state, that would be acceptable.  I would however suggest adding a comment pointing out the mistake and suggesting the author correct it if it is in fact a posting mistake, and not an error with his "real" code.

Comment: In other words: rollback

Comment: See edit.  Kind of, but I wouldn't actually click "rollback" because other acceptable edits besides this code change were made.

Comment: I agree. If the edit had only added the final `</div>`, it would have been reasonable. However the extra `>` on the first line raises a red flag: it shows that the original poster did not copy-paste their code.